# Starting scales on piano

Tags: piano, scales

I’ve been playing the piano for about 5 years so scales have become a kind of second nature to me. I’m currently playing 3 and 4 notes per tick at 92 for my scales. But this year I have had trouble with starting my scales, it feels at thought I am physically unable to start playing them even though I know I can. Can anyone help?

Comment: Are you asking about a psychological issue or a physical one?

Comment: It sounds like you practice scale drills, but it recently take time to get into the "flow." Can you add some detail about what you actually play for scale practice?

Answer (score 0):

I‘ve been drilled to practice scales - parallel and opposite movement, 2:2, 3:2, 4:3 and this by only activating each single finger.

I had years to find out by myself that there are some important additional movements:

- Rolling the hand, especially the wrist
- Following with the arms and shoulders, if needed thewhole body to the right and left side of the piano, like we do when we play arpeggios, skipping with the thumb from fourth to octave etc.

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean you can't start psychologically or physically?

Since many scales start with the thumb, there are several movements which play the thumb.  First, you can pronate down to it.  The same muscles you use to play trills and tremolos are the ones that can play the thumb.  Just use forearm rotation from the elbow and the thumb plays without using the thumb's muscles.

You could be playing too far in.  The keys are heavier on the inside so without curling, try to play all fingers using in/out motions to play on the outside edges.

The thumb should have a forward shift to it so you don't fall off the keys.  Sitting at the piano is unnatural so you need this constant forward shift.  If you totally relaxed, your arms would fall to your sides. There is no such thing as relaxation at the piano so you need constant alternating movements to maintain "relaxation."  As you learned in HS Physics, every motion must have an equal and opposite motion.  The good news is you can train yourself to minimize the opposite motion.

Maybe you are pressing too hard into the keybed?  You can't move if you are pressing down. Let gravity play the notes and your hand will always be free from strain.

Maybe you are abducting your fingers in preparation to play the next notes.  Spreading the fingers out creates instant tension. Learn to play with all five fingers together. The arm will get the fingers where they need to be.

There are multiple finger groupings and rotations involved in scale playing.  Your arm can change directions several times in one ascending octave scale.   It could be that you've been doing it incorrectly for the past few years and the tension is just hardwired into your brain. If this is the case you'll have to re-learn how to play.

Are there twists in your wrists?  Sometimes when players try to get forearm rotation in their arm (from the elbow) they do it from the wrist.  More tension ensues.

Play from the arm, shoulder, elbow.  The arm places the fingers, the fingers don't drag the arm behind it.  That will result in twists, weak feeling fingers and fatigue.

It could be that you are trying to play from the flexor muscles.  Your fingers don't have muscles.  They are moved from the muscles of the forearm.  The flexors are not fast muscles at all, they are designed for gripping things.   And, they are certainly not designed for independence because they are all interconnected and using two muscles to move one bone will result in tension, one of the muscles will have to submit.  The arm is designed for speed though, ironically.  For example, you don't throw a ball from the fingers, nor the wrist, nor the elbow, nor the shoulder.  The throw starts from the feet, abs, hips and back, then transfers to the shoulder, elbow, then fingers.  The wrist is a conduit.

Because your fingers are different lengths and the black keys are higher, you need an up movement from the forearm.  You must strike each key from above it coming straight down.  Like walking up stairs, your ascending foot must raise higher than the next step.  If not, you'll trip.  Piano keys are the same because of the different finger lengths and the higher black keys. You can't play them from below them.